# How to use conditional on Django template?

Tags: python, django

Im working on my django project. The home page of my project is to show all of my post and category-based post on the bottom after the first part. But my code isnt working and i dont know why. Please help me, im a django noob

#the word Opini is one of my post category

```
  {% for post in blog_posts %}
    <div class="card d-inline-flex m-1" style="width: 18rem;">
      <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.pk %}" >
        <img class="card-img-top postimg" src="{{ post.post_img.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
      </a>
      <h3>{{post.category}}</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-text text-center">{{ post.post_title }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{post.post_content|truncatechars:75|safe }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <h1> Opini </h1>
  {% for post in blog_posts %}
    {% if post.category == "Opini" %} 
    <div class="card d-inline-flex m-1" style="width: 18rem;">
      <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.pk %}" >
        <img class="card-img-top postimg" src="{{ post.post_img.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
      </a>
      <h3>{{post.category}}</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-text text-center">{{ post.post_title }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{post.post_content|truncatechars:75|safe }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
```

My Models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_by_category', args=[self.name])


class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    post_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='postImage/')  
    post_content = RichTextField(blank= True, null = True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-post_date"] 
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.post_title}'
```

When i run the code, only the first page works, when it comes to the second part, nothing appeared

Answer (score 0):

If "Opini" is the category name then you should compare it like this:

```
{% if post.category.name == "Opini" %}
```